# Prove that: $\cos(x) -1 < -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that:
>
> $$\cos(x) -1 < -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$$ for $x \ne 0$

I need to prove this using Cauchy's mean value theorem.

What I did:

$f(x) = \cos(x) -1$

$$g(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24}$$

If I can show that:

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\lt 1$ that would prove the original inequality

so,

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{g(x) - g(0)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$ for $0\lt c \lt x$

$$\dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \dfrac{-\sin(c)}{-c + \frac{c^3}{6}}$$

My problem is the following expression is not always less then 1! (for example $c=2.4$)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, do you know this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem ? 
If not, try to use $f(x)=\cos(x) -1 + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{24}$ and calculate $f'(x)$,$f''(x)$. Then make ​​an array of variation..

Comment: this question is specified to be solved using Cauchy mean value theorem, i am interested in knowing, why was my result doesnt contradict the original inequality and the real solution using this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem

Comment: Note that $f(x) \leqslant 0$ always, and $g(x) < 0$ for $0 < \lvert x\rvert < \sqrt{12}$. For small $\lvert x\rvert > 0$, your inequality should be $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 1.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer why did the sign flip ?

Comment: Because dividing an inequality by a negative number flips the sign. $-3 < -2$, but $$\frac{-3}{-2} = \frac{3}{2} > 1.$$

Comment: Because $g(x)$ is always negative we treat it like a negative number ?

Comment: @GinKin $g(x)$ is not _always_ negative. But when it is, you have $$f(x) < g(x) \iff (-g(x)) < (-f(x)) \iff 1 < \frac{-f(x)}{-g(x)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it will be easier to show that: $$ \cos x - 1 + \frac{x^2}2 < \frac{x^4}{24} $$

Define $f(x) = \cos x - 1 + \frac{x^2}2$, $g(x) = \frac{x^4}{24}$.
Now using the Cauchy MVT: $$ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)} = \frac{6(c-\sin c)}{c^3} $$

Now just show that $ h(x) = \frac{6(x-\sin x)}{x^3} $ is bounded above globably by $1$, and you'll get what you need.

Comment: I know this is a high school level question but how do you show that $x(2+\cos x)-3\sin x=0$ ? (that's the derivative equal to zero)

Comment: Frankly I have no idea( i.e I don't remember :) ). I assume you want to show that there is an extremum point. I think its enough to show that $h'(x) < 0$ for every $x < 0$ and $h'(x) > 0$ for every $x > 0$.

Comment: How do you do that in this case ?

Comment: You can show it as with a normal inequality, as you would usually do. ( MVT, Derivative stuff ). Remember when cosx goes up and when sinx goes down, that might help.

Comment: @GinKin, if you put $\;g(x):=x(2+\cos x)-3\sin x\;$, then $$g\left(-\frac\pi2\right)=-\pi+3<0\\g\left(\frac\pi2\right)=\pi-3>0$$

Comment: @DonAntonio but how does that prove that there's only one maximum ? or that for all $x$,  $g(x)$ doesn't go through zero again ?

Comment: Ah, I was just addressing your first comment, @GinKin : the above is one way to show that function vanishes somewhere (which, BTW, can be $\;x=0\;$ , as simple as that)