# Proving $\cos x < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^4}{24}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials

I wish to prove the following inequality for $x\ne 0$:
$$\cos x < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^4}{24}$$

**Using the fact that I already prove:**
$$\cos x > 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$$

My try:
$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^4}{24} + R_2(x)$ where $R_2(x)$ is the remainder with the order of $n=2$.

By Lagrange's form of the remainder:

$$R_2(x) = \frac{cos^{(3)}(c)}{(3)!}x^3 = \frac{\sin c}{6}x^3$$

WLOG we assume $x>0$ and $0<c<x$

Now, what's left to prove is that: $$R_2(x) < \frac{x^4}{24}$$

But, I got the strange result: $x<4$.

What did I do wrong / what should I do instead?

I wish to rely on this inequality: $\cos x > 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: did you try [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634602/prove-that-cosx-1-fracx22-fracx424?rq=1)?

Comment: Thank you. By the way, Where's my approach collapse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the symmetry of $\cos$ about $x=0$, we only need to prove it for positive $x$.  Since $\cos t\gt 1-\frac{t^2}{2!}$, we have for positive $x$ that 
$$\sin x=\int_0^x \cos t\,dt\gt \int_0^x \left(1-\frac{t^2}{2!}\right)\,dt=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}.$$
Do it again. We have 
$$1-\cos x=\int_0^x \sin t\,dt\gt \int_0^x \left(t-\frac{t^3}{3!}\right)\,dt,$$
which gives us what we want. And if we want to continue, there is nothing to stop us.

**Remark:** One can do it with differentiation.  We first prove that for positive $x$ we have $\sin x\gt x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$.

Let $f(x)=\sin x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)$. We have $f(0)=0$. To show that $f(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 0$, it is enough to show that $f(x)$ is increasing.

Note that $f'(x)=\cos x-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)$. By the result you want to use, we have $f'(x)\gt 0$ if $x\gt 0$. It follows that $f(x)$ is increasing.

For your question about $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$, do it again. Let $g(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cos x$. We have $g(0)=0$, and want to prove $g(x)$ is increasing for $x\gt 0$.

For this, we will use the fact that $g'(x)\gt 0$. Note that $g'(x)=\sin x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)$, and we have just shown that this is positive.

Comment: Thank you but it's part of Calculus I course, so integration isn't allowed :(

Comment: One can do basically the same thing with differentiation.